# Arguments shared between multiple instances of same block

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, custom-block

I have created a custom block and tried to insert it multiple times in the same page:

```
<block class="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Producttabs\CategoryProducts" name="category.products.slider1" template="MyCompany_MyModule::producttabs/category-items-new.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="string">31</argument>
        <argument name="block_title" xsi:type="string">Lorem ipsum</argument>
        <argument name="block_text" xsi:type="string">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>

<block class="MyCompany\MyModule\Block\Producttabs\CategoryProducts" name="category.products.slider2" template="MyCompany_MyModule::producttabs/category-items-new.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="string">32</argument>
        <argument name="block_title" xsi:type="string">Quod autem</argument>
        <argument name="block_text" xsi:type="string">Quod autem satis est, eo quicquid accessit, nimium est</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

`category-items-new.phtml` should display block arguments:

```
<h4><?php echo $block->getData('block_title'); ?></h4>
<p><?php echo $block->getData('block_text'); ?></p>
```

But instead of displaying:

```
<h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h4><h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
<p>Quod autem satis est, eo quicquid accessit, nimium est</p></h4>
```

I'm getting the first block data repeated twice:

```
<h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.